# How to use substr() inside an orderBy function in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

Good day,

I need to sort my result by using "orderBy" function in laravel but unfortunately the values in that column that I want to use has "j1_" before the actual number.. so I want to remove the first 3 character first but when I tried

```
orderBy(substr('x_fs_format_details.tree_xid', 3))
```

it gives me a "Column not found" error.

Is there a way to tweak this? thanks.

Comment: you need a built-in SGBD function to do that. what is your SGBD ?

Comment: Are you sure you have a column named 's_format_details.tree_xid'?

Comment: this may help http://laravel.io/forum/02-10-2014-orderby-with-my-custom-attributes

Comment: yes @BrokenBinary actually I tried doing it by raw query on sqlyog before posting it here "SELECT * FROM x_fs_format_details WHERE fs_xid ="3" ORDER BY tree_xid" and I get results

Comment: What he means is calling `substr('x_fs_format_details.tree_xid', 3)` returns `s_format_details.tree_xid`... And I doubt you have a colunm called that.

Comment: This is not possible to do it with Eloquent's `orderBy`.From what I understand you want a number sort on a string column.

Comment: yeah @YAAK I was also thinking about the same.. maybe I just look for some ways to do this

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you use MYSQL (the substring function might be different on other databases)

You can either make a new field on the fly:

```
$query->selectRaw('*, SUBSTR(x_fs_format_details.tree_xid, 3) AS substr_tree_xid')
      ->orderBy('substr_tree_xid')->get();
```

This has the advantage/disadvantage that the result of `SUBSTR` will be in your result. If you don't want that you can also use `SUBSTR` in the order by directly:

```
$query->orderByRaw('SUBSTR(x_fs_format_details.tree_xid, 3)')->get();
```

Comment: Can also achieve this using `Model::orderByRaw('SUBSTR(x_fs_format_details.tree_xid, 3)')->get();`. Cleaner if you don't need this extra data in your result.